# Run a dbus program in crontab , how to know about the SESSION id?

Tags: kde, d-bus

I need to run some program within crontab , but how can the program know about dbus session id ? it's only available for programs launched by session managers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is somewhat similar to [accessing the X display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-to-access-x-display-from-a-cron-job-when-using-gdm3) and [finding the location of the X cookie file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display). (Also, refer to these questions if you want to launch a GUI program on the user's display.)

Dbus stores the session address in a file in `~/.dbus/session-bus`. The name of the file is `$machine_id-$display_number`, where `$machine_id` is a randomly generated number stored in `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id` and `$display_number` is the X display number (`$DISPLAY` is `:$display_number` or `:$display_number.$screen_number`). The file in `~/.dbus/session-bus` is parseable by a shell and contains definitions for `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID`.

```
dbus_session_file=~/.dbus/session-bus/$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-0
if [ -e "$dbus_session_file" ]; then
  . "$dbus_session_file"
  export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
  dbus-send …
fi
```

Beware that there's no guarantee that the dbus daemon is still available. The user may have logged out.

An alternative method is to find the PID of a process in the desktop session, and obtain the dbus address from its environment.

```
export $(</proc/$pid/environ tr \\0 \\n | grep -E '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')
```

If the crontab is running as root and you want to communicate with the session of whatever user is logged in on the console, see [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root)

Comment: One caveat to this: `dbus` may store the session bus address in `$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/`, but `dbus-broker` does not. So the first method won't work on any system that's migrated away from the original `dbus` implementation to `dbus-broker`. (That list consists of at least: Fedora; most likely RHEL an CentOS as well.)

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment on [Vincenzo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137620/133107), but I find his answer works best for me on KDE4.

I've had to slightly modify the command though. For me it's:

```
ps -u yourlogin e | grep -Eo 'dbus-daemon.*ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-[A-Za-z0-9]{10}' | tail -c35
```

Notice `ADDRESS` in capital letters.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you know the pid of the gnome session manager, then you read the environment from `/proc` filesystem.

```
GNOME_SESSION_PID=<PID_OF_GNOME_SESSION> 
READ_SESSION_COOKIE="$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$GNOME_SESSION_PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)"
```

Use the SESSION id then, with other programs like notify-send or dbus* tools.

Cheers.

Comment: very impressive , actually i'm running KDE4 , so i looked for `plasma-desktop` instead, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -u yourlogin e | grep -Eo 'dbus-daemon.*address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-[A-Za-z0-9]{10}' | tail -c35
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes DBus must have a x session.
Like earlier answers, 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' must have a value before starting . However, you could use 'dbus-launch' to create this value. Following snippet could be put in a script called from crontab.

```
if test -z "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" ; then
  eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`
fi
echo "D-Bus daemon address is:"
echo "$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"

# -E to export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. Crucial to make DBUS work.
sudo -u <user> -E <program>
```

One setback with this solution is that the session might hang around after you've stopped your software.

Comment: +1 for the `-E` flag to sudo

Comment: Correction: Dbus doesn't require a session. (How could it require an X session, when so many distros have migrated to Wayland?) **`dbus-launch`** requires a session manager, true. There's a separate utility, `dbus-run-session`, that can be used to run terminal commands in their own session bus. In a crontab that's probably a better choice. Either way, this won't merely "create [the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS] value", it'll create an entirely separate **session bus** instance. If you notice, you get a different value for `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` every time you run it.