# How can I run a program as another user in every way?

Tags: sudo, users, gnome-keyring

## Background

I'm trying to restart some programs (`mail-notification` and `stalonetray`) regularly, as they appear to die frequently. I want to set restart them whenever NetworkManager reconnects. Hence, I have them triggered by a script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`.

## Scripting

I can create a script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u foo_user pkill mail-notificati -x
sudo -u foo_user DISPLAY=:0 mail-notification &
```

This works fine if I run it directly as a user. However, if I call it from root's script, it fails. I am prompted to enter the passwords for `mail-notification`; it cannot read Gnome Keyring.

How can I run this program as `foo_user` in every way?

Comment: What does "in every way" mean? Every program that a user runs can have different environment, so saying that (for example) `DISPLAY` should be set for it to be "in every way" doesn't make much sense. You'd need to define this question more for it to make sense.

Comment: @ChrisDown I mean I want it to work when running the script as `root` as it does when running the script as `foo_user`. I appreciate that `DISPLAY` isn't necessarily relevant here, but included it as an example of what I was doing.

Comment: That still doesn't clarify, because "doing the same thing when run as root as when run as a user" doesn't make sense -- an environment is per-process, not per-user.

Comment: @ChrisDown Sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand the distinction in this case. Here, I'm asking to run the `mail-notification` process as in `foo_user`'s environment.

Comment: How do you know `foo_user` is logged in, and on which display?  On a single-user system it's perhaps reasonable to assume that it's always `:0.0` but it is not reasonable to assume that the user is logged in at all times.  Anyway, this makes more sense to run within the X session script of `foo_user`, which will remove both your original problem and the complications it caused you to want to try to solve.

Comment: @tripleee In this particular case, I presume that `foo_user` is logged in, and the `DISPLAY` is correct (and it works fine with `stalonetray`). I suspect I'm missing something else. Could you please provide more information on how to run it within the X session script? That sounds promising.

Comment: Different distros and different desktop managers have different defaults etc.  Traditionally you would add something to the user's `$HOME/.xsession` script; modern desktop managers typically allow you to click and drool an executable script to be added to the user's startup actions.  The script itself could just be a simple loop which wakes up every *n* seconds and checks if something needs to be relaunched.

Comment: Tangentially related, hopefully useful: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch07.en.html esp. 7.5.3.

Comment: The point is that users don't have environments, processes do. Without knowing what process should be mimicked, it's not possible to know what it means to "have the same environment" as another user.

Comment: Maybe Gnome Keyring needs (another) environment variable set -- one that's in the shell startup files that you could get with `sudo -i`?

Comment: @tripleee Ah, I understand now. Yes, that could be another option. Alternatively I could put it in `foo_user`'s crontab. However, I was more curious in a general solution, which might be triggered by root activities such as NetworkManager hooks, udev, pm-suspend (resume), etc.

Comment: @ChrisDown But in this case I know the specific process that I'm trying to make work. Perhaps I just need to make my title more specific?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks, but that didn't work. I tried `sudo sudo -i -u foo_user my_script`, but it still couldn't access Gnome Keyring

Comment: sudo strips environment variables by default (env_reset); maybe Gnome Keyring needs one that's getting stripped out? Compare `env` as foo_user versus `sudo -i -u foo_user env`.

Answer (score 12):

## In 2021

#### In short:

To run a command as another user you can use this commands:

`runuser -u user -- command`
can be used only by root to run commands as another user.
do not require authentication.
do not create log messages.
has permission limitations and issues.

`su - user -c command`
can be used by any user.
require authentication as target user.
create message in `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`.

`sudo -u user command`
can be used by the user with root privileges or the user from the `sudoers` file.
require authentication as current user (you).
create message in `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`.

`pkexec --user user command`
can be used by any user.
require authentication as target user.
create message in `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`.
replacement for GUI tools such as `gksu` or `gksudo`.

#### More info:

[Linux Run Command As Another User](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/)

#### Run a GUI application as another user:

If you want to run a GUI application as another user, you need first allow to the target user connecting to your display:
`xhost +si:localuser:user`
then use `runuser`/`su`/`sudo`/`pkexec` to run the application,
and then use `xhost` to prevent the subsequent connections:
`xhost -si:localuser:user`

Comment: Excellent answer! I tried to use this to run spotify as a non-privileged system user. Your answers, especially for running a GUI app, worked for me. However, I did neet to pass in my DISPLAY var through sudo using the -E flag. Also, I was ignorant and didn't realize `localuser` is that literal string. Finally, a gui app may fail to various other issues with expecting a normal user's profile. HTH

Comment: Regarding GUI: Is this safe though? Can `user` send arbitrary input after having been given access to the display?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use good old **su** :

`man 1 su`

This command opens a sub-shell as the user you want to impersonate. 
As root you can use it without being prompted for a password.

`su foo_user -c whatevercommandyouwant`

Works from scripts too.

Comment: I'm not sure what `-x` is (I get `su: invalid option -- 'x'`), but after removing that, it still fails as per the question.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, but my aim is not to provide a one shot solution but to tell you how the command `su` works.  If you did a direct cut and paste you may have got an error. But, that's exactly why I added a link to the `su` **man page** as the first thing. Please cut and paste this into the shell and see what it says ;)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Are you suggesting that `su` will provide a different `env` to `sudo` that should fix my problem? If so, then that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes. Again: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html

"   su allows to run commands with a substitute user and group ID.

       When called without arguments, su defaults to running an interactive
       shell as root.

       For backward compatibility, su defaults to not change the current
       directory and to only set the environment variables HOME and SHELL
       (plus USER and LOGNAME if the target user is not root). "

**anyway** `sudo` has nothing to do with that, `sudo su` does. `sudo` grants permissions to run commands that require specific privileges to your user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interact with a GUI from a process that isn't started from that GUI, you need to set a few environment variables: at least `DISPLAY`, possibly [also `XAUTHORITY`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) if it isn't in the default location, and for many modern programs you need to [set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/run-a-dbus-program-in-crontab-how-to-know-about-the-session-id/28496#28496).

But a more reliable approach for your problem would be to not restart those programs from NetworkManager. In addition to the difficulty of successfully launching them, you also need to worry about whether you're logged in at all, and if there might be other users and other displays to consider, and so on. Instead, *kill* those programs, but don't restart them. In your normal session, instead of starting them directly, start them from a supervisor that restarts them if they die. I think systemd includes this functionality (but I don't know how to use it); or you can use dedicated supervisor programs such as [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), [supervise](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html), …

Answer (score 0):

Read, copy and install
[`run-as`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/run-as),
a Bash and a Python script which wrap up usage of
`machinectl`, `xhost` and of managing running `dbus` and setting
variables to run a graphical application for you:

```
run-as <user> <command>
```

To run a graphical application do

```
run-as -X <user> <command>
```

##### References

- [xorg - How to run a graphical application as another user? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710047/313554)