# Access to user's session D-bus from their cron commands

Tags: cron, d-bus

What is needed to give cron commands access to the session bus (if it is running)?

It used to work for me, on Debian Stretch (testing) since switching systemd until relatively recently (might have been month or two ago). The strange thing is that while I strongly suspect this is controlled by the PAM configuration, the only change that happened to `/etc/pam.d` recently enough was adding some calls to `pam_selinux` to `pam.d/systemd-user`.

So what should I look for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable isn't propagated to the cron environment.

At least under Gnome, the bus isn't made "discoverable" (as documented in the "AUTOMATIC LAUNCHING" section of the [`dbus-launch(1)` man page](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html)) via files in `$HOME/.dbus/session-bus`. This leaves anything run in your crontab without a way to discover `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and contact the session D-Bus.

I'll take your word for it that it worked in the past, possibly due to use of `$HOME/.dbus` or the existence of actual `/tmp/dbus-$TMPNAM` files referenced in `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` (which is normally set to something resembling `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-GkJdpPD4sk,guid=0001e69e075e5e2`). As the `dbus-cleanup-sockets(1)` man page explains:

> On Linux, this program is essentially useless, because D-Bus defaults
> to using "abstract sockets" that exist only in memory and don't have a
> corresponding file in /tmp.

However, we can use a variation on the idea presented in an ubuntuforum post, [Attach to existing DBUS session over SSH](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059023yqq), to discover the session D-Bus of an existing user session on the local machine from within the cron environment and set `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` accordingly.

While the technique used there discovers the environment from commonly-running processes like `nautilus`, `pulseaudio`, and `trackerd`, and requires that one or more of them be running in the active session, I recommend a more basic approach.

All of the common desktop environment session managers (`gnome-session`, `lxsession`, and `kded4`) have `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` set in their environment, even though they're started before `dbus-daemon` and have lower PIDs. So, it makes the most sense to just use whatever session manager corresponds to your desktop environment.

I wrote the following script, placed in `$HOME/bin/test-crontab-dbus.sh`, to test access to the existing session bus:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
SESSION_MANAGER=lxsession
OUTFILE=/tmp/${USER}-cron-dbus.txt

export $(cat /proc/$(pgrep "$SESSION_MANAGER" -u "$USER")/environ \
  |egrep -z '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')

date >> $OUTFILE
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus \
   / org.freedesktop.DBus.GetId 2>> $OUTFILE
if test "$?" -eq 0; then
    echo "Success contacting session bus!" >> $OUTFILE
fi
```

The `SESSION_MANAGER=lxsession` above is appropriate for a main desktop session running under LXDE, under Gnome you'd set `SESSION_MANAGER=gnome-session`, and under KDE you'd use `SESSION_MANAGER=kded4`.

If the job in the crontab has access to the session bus, you'll see something like the following in the output:

```
Fri Dec 18 15:27:02 EST 2015
Success contacting session bus!
```

Otherwise, you'll see the error message output by `dbus-send`.

Obviously, you can substitute any other method of testing connectivity to the session bus, including whatever operation you actually need to perform via a cron job.

Comment: You can leverage dbus itself to ping to see if the bus is alive, e.g. if `$candidate` is a value you think is a valid bus address, `dbus-send --bus="$candidate" --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.GetId` will exit with success/fail+error-message if that bus is alive

Comment: @Cheetah : Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! I've incorporated your suggested method into my answer, eliminating the dependency on `dbus-test`.

Comment: Under KDE5, the correct value for SESSION_MANAGER is "startkde", and you may need to add the "-n" argument to pgrep to ensure it only returns the latest instance of startkde (my system had 2 instances running, and only the latest one had any environment variables set).

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28496/73278 for another way of getting DBUS_SESSION_ADDRESS

Comment: @GregBell Agreed, that does seem easier! Though, interestingly, my `$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/` file is named `$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-1`, not `-0` as in the example there.

Comment: @JonathanWatts Things seem to have reached a similar point with GNOME. Under 3.34 I have _no_ `gnome-session` processes running at all. Instead, my logged-in user has `/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary` running (also two of them, one with the args `--systemd-service --session=gnome`) as well as a `/usr/libexec/gnome-session-ctl`. However, in my case all three processes have `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` set in their environment. Still, as @GregBell pointed out https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28496/73278 kind of makes the whole thing moot.

Comment: Hmm, or maybe not. I only just noticed it, but not only is the file in my `$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/` named differently from the example at that link, it's also from _JUNE_. Something _did_ create that file at one point, but it's clearly not being updated. The `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID` it lists doesn't match any currently-running process, and the address points to `/tmp/dbus-$linenoise`. Whereas in my current session, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is set to `unix:path=/run/user/1000/dbus` (a socket that currently exists).

Comment: (The situation in my previous comment, with `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` now pointing at an actual on-disk socket path, is undoubtedly the result of Fedora switching over to `dbus-broker` as its DBus daemon.)