# Why can't I run GUI apps with sudo from crontab when I can with sudo: “No protocol specified”?

Tags: scripting, cron

Here's a little background as it might be the cause to the problem. I'm running Armbian legacy Jessie on a Orange Pi Zero. It does not include an desktop so I've installed X, lightdm and Xfce. I haven't managed to start X on boot so I have a @reboot line in crontab that executes a script that includes this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while ! ping -c 1 -W 1 192.168.1.100; do
    sleep 1
done
/usr/bin/startx
```

everything works perfectly (I have autologin enabled and it starts the Mumble client on 1:0). I then have a python script that monitors my GPIO (a push to talk button) and send "Ctrl + 1" if the button is pressed. Mumble is listening to that combination and starts broadcasting when it is pressed.

I must run run my python script as root to be able to access the GPIO, so I have added these lines to `/etc/profile` (so that root can access X):

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/icuser/.Xauthority
```

As I said this works perfectly when executed with sudo:

```
sudo python /home/icuser/sendptt_zero.py
```

but when I execute my script with (@reboot in crontab):

```
sudo /usr/bin/python /home/icuser/sendptt_zero.py >> /home/hallgren/ic.log 2>&1 &
```

I get this in my ic.log file (when I press the gpio button that starts the emulate keyboard key function in Python (I'm using http://www.autopy.org/)):

```
No protocol specified
Could not open main display
```

My Python script also has this line (won't work without it):

```
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':1.0'
```

Do you have any ideas on how to get it to start X automatically and why it works from command line with sudo but not when started from crontab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display) although [How to access X display from a cron job when using gdm3](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-to-access-x-display-from-a-cron-job-when-using-gdm3) would be a better match by title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron doesn't use `/etc/profile`.

Write the variables at the top of your `crontab` file.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer! I added export DISPLAY=:1.0 and
 export XAUTHORITY=/home/icuser/.Xauthority to my crontab and now I only get Could not open main display. An improvement but still not there...

Comment: That's because it takes time for Xorg to be fully started, so put a some seconds `sleep` before trying, or write a loop which tries more times to connect to X server.

Comment: OK, I've now tried with sleep up to 30 seconds before starting my python script and I still get Could not open main display. I have a X11vnc running and I can see that Xorg is started long before the python script is started.

Comment: Putting your python command into `~/.xinitrc` is not option?

Comment: Why not, but how do I do that? :) I tried to add exec sudo /usr/bin/python /home/... in .xinitrc but that is not the righ way as it didn't start...

Comment: skip `exec`, it's not a window manager. And add `&` at the of line.

Comment: Now I understand why the python script is not executed. When I made the .xintrc file I can't start x with startx anymore. I just get xinit: `connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`

Comment: OK, now I got it to work. I added everything on the same line in my bash script like `DISPLAY=:1.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/icuser/.Xauthority sudo /usr/bin/python /home/icuser...`